# Rotating the contents on my canvas in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transform

Can I rotate everything on my canvas and keep the quality of my image without resizing all of my contents?

I have tried using the image rotation tool but I need to actually rotate my objects. I also tried to resize the objects after I rotated the image but when I do that it distorts my objects leaving them in an ugly state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet would be to use a Smart Object.

1. Open your Layers palette (<kbd>Window > Layers</kbd> or <kbd>F7</kbd>);
2. Select the layers containing your objects in the Layers palette;
3. <kbd>right-click</kbd> and choose <kbd>Convert to Smart Object</kbd>;
4. Do your transformation / rotation with the Smart Object.

When creating a Smart Object, you essentially nest one `.psd` file in another. The object behaves as a single layer, allowing you to do everything you'd do to a single layer. It is, however, still editable: <kbd>double click</kbd> the Smart Object layer thumbnail and it will open as a separate file in a new window. This allows you to edit the contents of the Object. If you <kbd>Save</kbd> and close the object, it will update in the parent file.

Comment: @Will If my answer solved your problem, please consider ticking the checkmark next to it to mark it as the 'accepted' answer. This is good for our site stats and shows visitors that their questions do get good answers. If later a better answer comes by, you can always switch the checkmark to that answer.